# What does Intel 4th generation black logo means?

Tags: dell-inspiron, intel-core-i7

I have seen black color Intel sticker on Dell Inspiron 15 5547 which has Core i7 4510U processor. Is this black color means extreme edition of it. I did check intel for extreme edition of this processor but couldn't find details. This sticker is similar to what I have seen. If this is the extreme edition what are the benefit of it rather than the regular?

[image: Core i7 Black Logo]

Comment: It used to mean Extreme Edition in previous generations, but now I believe Extreme is blue as well: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819117404

Comment: Extreme Edition doesn't mean you'll get any benefits, it's a marketing thing to mean that it is a higher-end CPU. If you actually want to know benefits, you have to compare it to another CPU.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 15 5547 is not a gaming laptop either. So it won't be extreme edition. There should be something else meant by the color.

Comment: Except there isn't. The 4510U is NOT Exteme product. [Here](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/79318/Intel-High-End-Desktop-Processors#@Desktop) is a list of those products.

Comment: @Nishantha - Nothing.  It is just the color of the sticker.

Comment: @Nishantha [your processor specs here](http://ark.intel.com/products/81015/Intel-Core-i7-4510U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz) Not extreme edition or it would say so.

Answer (score 1):

when the processor speed goes  more than 3GHz then they give black logo.so verify while buying.
because many laptops have processor speed b/w 1.7 to 2.7 GHz so they give blue logo for it.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?